Find the number of single-digit solutions to $a+b^2+c^4=100a+10b+c$
I want to know that how many triplets $(a,b,c)$ satisfy the condition
$$a+b^{2}+c^{4}=100a+10b+c ,$$
where $a,b,c \in \{1, \ldots, 9\}$.
Recently I came to know about the solutions to
$$a+b^{2}+c^{3}=100a+10b+c ,$$
namely,
\begin{split}
1+3^{2}+5^{3}=135, \qquad
1+7^{2}+5^{3}=175, \\
5+1^{2}+8^{3}=518, \qquad
5+9^{2}+8^{3}=598 .
\end{split}
Question: Is there any other way to prove that these are all of the (single-digit) solutions?

Similarly I tried to find the number of triplets $(a,b,c)$ satisfying the similar condition
$$a+b^{2}+c^{4}=100a+10b+c ,$$
again by trial and error. But interestingly I got none.
Question: Are there no solutions to the equation? If so, how can one prove it?

You might want to say what your restriction on $a$, $b$, and $c$ are.  Otherwise, your third condition has the "solution" $(a,b,c) = (35,508,123,152,821,9603,-7700)$.

For instance, you probably don't want $a=b=c=0$.

$(a,b,c)=(970387,99,99)$  works (found by machine).

I think the smallest all-positive-integers example for the third condition is $(a,b,c) = (14,16,6)$

There are many solutions, see this

Please edit your posted question to indicate what restrictions that you want on each of $~a,b,c.~$  Please do not respond with a comment.  For example, do you intend that $~a~$ must be some element in $~{1,2,3,\cdots,9}$?

What I meant to say is that $abc$ is a number like $135$. Here $abc$ doesn't mean $a×b×c$.

First of all, you didn't explicitly respond to my question.  That is, you did not explicitly specify which set of values are allowed for each of the variables $~a,b,c.~$  Second of all, I repeat : please do not respond with a comment.  Instead, please edit your posted question.

See my discussion for the case of powers $1, 2, 3$ here.

In python, import itertools and then def roorkee(m: int, n: int, k: int) -> list[tuple[int, int, int]]: return [ (a, b, c) for a, b, c in itertools.product(range(1, 10), repeat=3) if a**m + b**n + c**k == 100 * a + 10 * b + c ]. Now roorkee(1,2,4) will give you a list of all solutions, and similarly for other powers

Consider
$$a + b^2 + c^3 = \overline{abc} = 100 a + 10 b + c, \qquad a, b, c \in \{1, \ldots, 9\} .$$
Rearranging gives $c^3 = 99 a + (10 - b) b + c \geq 109,$
so $c \geq 5$.
Now collecting like terms in $b$ and reducing modulo $11$ (because it eliminates $a$ from the equation ) gives $b^2 + b + (c^3 - c) \equiv_{11} 0$. If this equation has a solution $b$ for some $a, c$, then the discriminant in $b$ of the quadratic, namely,
$$2^2 (-c^3 + c + 3),$$
is a square modulo $11$, which further limits the possible values for $c$ to $5, 8, 9$.
For $c = 5$, for example, substituting yields $(b - 3) (b - 7) \equiv_{11} 0$, so $b \in \{3, 7\}$. Substituting $b = 3$ in the original equation and solving for $a$ yields the solution $\overline{abc} = \boxed{135}$, and instead setting $b = 7$ yields $\boxed{175}$. Repeating the process for $c = 8, 9$ yields the solutions $\boxed{518}$ and $\boxed{598}$ and no others.

Now consider the equation $$a + b^2 + c^4 = \overline{abc} = 100 a + 10 b + c .$$ If we again require that $a, b, c \in \{1, \ldots, 9\}$ (which I suspect is the intent), we can show quickly that there are no solutions. Proceeding as before gives $c^4 \geq 109$, so $c \geq 4$. On the other hand, $c^4 < 100 a + 10 b + c \leq 999$, so $c \leq 5$.

If $c = 4$, substituting and reducing modulo $9$ gives $b^2 \equiv_9 b$, so $b \in \{1, 9\}$. Instead reducing modulo $11$ gives $0 \equiv_{11} b^2 + b + 10 \equiv_{11} (b - 3) (b - 7)$, so $b \in \{3, 7\}$, a contradiction.

If $c = 5$, substituting and reducing modulo $3$ gives $b^2 \equiv_3 b + 1$, which has no solution.


The positive integer solutions respectively minimizing $a, b, c$ are:

$a$: $(\color{red}{4}, 18, 4)$
$b$: $(511 + 13,499 k + 1\,350 \cdot99  k^2 + 60 \cdot 99^2 k^3 + 99^3 k, \color{red}{3}, 15 + 99 k)$, $k \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$
$c$:
$( p + q k + 99 k^2, r + 99 k, \color{red}{1})$, $k \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}$, $(p, q, r) \in \{(24, 98, 54), (25, 100, 55), (89, 100, 99), (109, 208, 109)\}$.

The positive integer solution minimizing $\operatorname{max}\{a, b, c\}$ is $(14, 16, 6)$, the solution Eric Towers mentioned in the comments.
Remark
The essentially distinct solutions of $$a^l + b^m + c^n = 100 a + 10 b + c, \qquad a, b, c \in \{1, \ldots, 9\}, \quad l, m, n \in \Bbb Z_{\geq 0}, $$ are:
\begin{array}{cl}
\hline
(l, m, n) & \overline{abc} \\
\hline
(0, 1, 6) & \color{#df0000}{733} \\
(0, 1, 7) & \color{#0000df}{132} \\
(0, 2, 3) & \boxed{\color{#0000df}{135}}, \boxed{\color{#0000df}{175}}, 739, \color{#df0000}{779} \\
(0, 2, 4) & 635, 675 \\
(0, 3, 3) & \color{#0000df}{153}, 794 \\
(0, 3, 7) & 472 \\
(0, 4, 3) & 653 \\
(0, 6, 0) & \color{#0000df}{731} \\
(0, 6, 1) & 732, 734, 735, 736, \color{#df0000}{737}, 738, 739 \\
\hline
(1, 0, 3) & 347, \boxed{\color{#0000df}{518}} \\
(1, 1, 3) & 739 \\
(1, 1, 4) & 264 \\
(1, 2, 3) & \boxed{598} \\
(1, 3, 2) & 267 \\
(1, 3, 3) & \color{#df0000}{226}, \color{#df0000}{373} \\
(1, 3, 4) & \color{#df0000}{994} \\
(1, 3, 5) & 463 \\
\hline
(2, 0, 3) & 538 \\
(2, 1, 3) & 357 \\
(2, 3, 2) & 794 \\
(2, 4, 5) & \color{#df0000}{333} \\
(2, 6, 3) & 935 \\
(2, 9, 2) & 629 \\
\hline
(3, 0, 3) & 946 \\
(3, 0, 5) & 973 \\
(3, 1, 3) & \color{#df0000}{377} \\
(3, 3, 0) & \color{#0000df}{371} \\
(3, 3, 1) & 372, 374, 375, 376, 378, 379 \\
(3, 4, 2) & 849 \\
(3, 4, 3) & \color{#df0000}{445}, 935 \\
(3, 5, 3) & \color{#df0000}{334} \\
\hline
(4, 2, 5) & \color{#df0000}{373} \\
(4, 5, 3) & \color{#df0000}{332} \\
\hline
(5, 0, 7) & 372 \\
(5, 1, 3) & 375 \\
(5, 1, 5) & 283 \\
(5, 3, 2) & 264 \\
(5, 7, 3) & \color{#df0000}{224} \\
\hline
(7, 1, 7) & 262 \\
(7, 3, 0) & 254 \\
\hline
(8, 0, 0) & 258 \\
(8, 1, 0) & 263 \\
\hline
\end{array}
The remaining solutions are those produced from an above entry by

replacing the exponent of a $1$ digit with any other positive integer (e.g., since $\color{#0000df}{135}$ is a solution for $(l, m, n) = (0, 2, 3)$, it is also a solution for $(1, 2, 3), (2, 2, 3)$, etc.)}, or
switching the exponents on repeated digits (e.g., since $\color{#df0000}{733}$ is a solution for $(0, 1, 6)$, it is also one for $(0, 6, 1)$).


This may not be a very elegant solution, but the equation you are after is
$$-99a + (b^2 - 10b) + (c^4 - c) = 0$$
and you want to show that this is not true for $a, b, c \in \{1, 2, \dots, 9\}$.
It is easy to check that in this range, we have
$$-99a \in \{-99, -198, -297, -396, -495, -594, -693, -792, -891\}\\
b^2 - 10b \in \{1^2 - 10(1), 2^2 - 10(2), \dots, 9^2 - 10(9)\}
= \{-9, -16, -21, -24, -25\}\\
c^4 - c \in \{1^4 - 1, 2^4 - 2, \dots, 9^4 - 9\}
= \{0, 14, 240, 1020, 3120, 7770, 16800, 32752, 59040\}$$
where in the second equation, we used the symmetry of $b^2-10b$.
Now, it is just a matter of checking by hand that two elements from the first two sets do not sum up to any element from the third set.

By maximizing the $RHS$, we have $RHS$ $\leq 999$, so $c \leq 5$.
If $c = 1,2 $ we have $LHS \leq 100 < RHS$.
If $ c=3$, then $a \stackrel{?}{=} 1$ but $(1,b,3)$ gives a quadratic equation where $b$ is not an integer.
If $c = 4$, $b \geq 7 \implies a \stackrel{?}{=} 3 $ but $(3,b,4)$ gives a quadratic equation where $b$ is not an integer.
If $c = 4,  b < 7 \implies a \stackrel{?}{=} 2$ but $(2,b,4)$ gives a quadratic equation where $b$ is not an integer.
If $c = 5$, then $a \stackrel{?}{=} 6,7$ but $((6 \lor 7),b,5)$ both give quadratic equations where $b$ is either not an integer or does not satisfy $1 \leq b \leq 9$.
This strategy only uses $5$ cases which can all be checked by a simple application of the quadratic formula and "$\stackrel{?}{=}$" denotes possible solutions that are checked by this application. The discounting of others is immediate.
You can simplify everything further by restricting $a,b$ at the same time and max-min each side for the quadratic equation (making the quadratic formula unnecessary), but I'll leave that to you.
